# Start WinDbg right after program crashes

Tags: windbg

If you look at [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/wmnr2KhArZk?t=12m31s), you can see that WinDbg is automatically executed when the process dies.

I've followed the tutorial and tried to do the same on my system. I first ran `windbg -I`, and then changed the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Auto` registry key to `0`. Is there any other step that I'm missing?

Comment: Is the process that you are debugging 32 or 64 bit? The WinDbg -I option is available in both 32 and 64-bit variations. The 64-bit settings will be set in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug] and the 32-bit in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]. Try running the -I option from both the 32 and 64-bit versions of WinDbg.

Comment: Is there maybe a library you're using that's fiddling with     [SetUnhandleExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[SetErrorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx) so that the kernel32 code does not get as far as interpreting the AeDebug flag? Another stupid question - are you certain your process crashes and not aborts?

Answer (score 3):

Running the 64-bit version of WinDbg with `-I` command line option creates both 64 bit and 32 bit `AeDebug` entries. This can easily be proven with Process Monitor:

[image: WinDbg x64 AeDebug creation]

The 32-bit version of WinDbg creates 32 bit entries only. So, if you ran the 32 bit version, 64 bit programs are not handled. That's what I expect has happened. Another option would be that you ran it without administrative privileges and didn't read the failure message carefully.

In case you want both 32-bit and 64-bit crashes to be handled by WinDbg, run `WinDbg -I` for both versions. You'll find that WinDbg is smart enough to handle any order:

- WinDbg32 will overwrite an existing entry created by WinDbg64 before
- WinDbg64 will not overwrite an existing entry created by WinDbg32 before

Although WinDbg64 can debug 32 bit applications, it cannot load 32 bit extension DLLs, therefore you typically want both debuggers registered, not only the 64 bit version.

Comment: I'm only running the 32 bit version of WinDbg (although the registry keys that you mention seem to correspond to the 64 bit). WinDbg -I does seem to overwrite the AeDebug/Auto key back to 1. The application that I'm running is also 32 bit. I don't see any entries for the 32 bit keys in (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug). The application still does not load.

Comment: @Abundance: a) which version of WinDbg do you use? Make sure you use a new version like 6.2.9200 or 6.3.9600. b) Do you have a 32 bit version of Windows? In that case there is no Wow6432Node. The `Auto` [setting (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only controls whether WinDbg is started immediately or there is a dialog box before.